# File write of unpickled byte array has no permissions set by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have deserialized file data in this dictionary arranged as follows -

```
[filename1 : bytearray with file contents]  
[filename2 : bytearray with file contents]  
[filename3 : bytearray with file contents]  
...
```

Now, when I write the data to disk at my destination folder using

```
    for f,bArr in depickled_.items():
        with open(os.path.join(r"S:\test", f), "wb") as fWr:
            fWr.write(bytearray(bArr))
            fWr.close() # <- probably redundant
```

The files are getting written as expected, but they have no permissions applied to them by default which I find odd. Therefore, I cannot open any of the written files as is, but when I fiddle with the security settings to allow myself read access then they open as expected.

Any idea what's going wrong and how I can fix it? I am the sole administrator (and user) of this computer.

More info:

- Python version 3.7
- Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some permissions using pywin32 module.

```
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con
from win32 import win32api

for f,bArr in depickle_.items():
        full_path = os.path.join(r"S:\test", f) 
        # with open(full_path, "wb+") as fWr:
        fd = os.open(full_path, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY, 0o777) # will probably work for linux
        with open(fd, 'wb') as fWr:
            fWr.write(bytearray(bArr))
            fWr.close()

    # user, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", win32api.GetUserName())
    user, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "Everyone")
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(full_path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()

    # Delete all existing permissions        
    for index in range(0, dacl.GetAceCount()):
        dacl.DeleteAce(0)

    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, user)
    sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0) 
    win32security.SetFileSecurity(full_path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```