# Permission error when writing to files using Python 3.8

Tags: python

I am splitting a large wordlist by length of the word
i didn't find a different approach for it so i decided to write a script in python for it.

say **test.txt** has

> word
>
> words

i want it to make new text files based on length of line and write the line to it

**4.txt**

> word

**5.txt**

> words

**CODE**

```
import os
import sys

basefile = open(sys.argv[1],'rt')
print("Writing.....")
os.mkdir(str(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0]))
os.chdir(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0])
#print(basefile)
for line in basefile:
    cpyfile=open(str(len(line.strip()))+'.txt',mode = 'a',encoding = 'utf-8')
    cpyfile.write(line)
    cpyfile.close()
print("Done")
basefile.close()
```

It works for small files but for larger files it gives out an error after a while

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '10.txt'
```

or

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '11.txt'
```

the error file is completely random too and the previous lines written are perfectly okay.

I have tried it on **windows using powershell** and using **gitbash**

Any help is appreciated and thanks

Comment: Can you check the file permissions? Right click on the file written -> Properties -> security tab?

This may be similar to [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017630/file-write-of-unpickled-byte-array-has-no-permissions-set-by-default)

Comment: Some time ago I had similar problems on windows. Workaround was to do a several retries with increasing pause between each try. It didn't look fancy like many windows-related issues. But it worked

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are running into the issue that Windows does not allow two programs to open the same file at once.  I'm not sure what the second program would be.  Maybe a virus scanner?  Your program works unaltered on Ubuntu using /usr/share/dict/american-english, so I think this may be a Windows thing.

In any case, I think you can solve this by keeping the files open while the program is running.

```
import os
import sys

basefile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
print("Writing.....")
os.mkdir(str(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0]))
os.chdir(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0])
# print(basefile)
files = {}
try:
    for line in basefile:
        cpyfilename = str(len(line.strip()))+'.txt'
        cpyfile = files.get(cpyfilename)
        if cpyfile is None:
            cpyfile = open(cpyfilename, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
            files[cpyfilename] = cpyfile
        cpyfile.write(line)
finally:
    for cpyfile in files.values():
        # Not strictly necessary because the program is about to end and
        # auto-close the files.
        cpyfile.close()
print("Done")
basefile.close()
```